# Criar página personalizada para registro de usuário

Tags: wordpress

Estou precisando criar uma página personalizada para cadastro de usuários no wordpress.

Além da forma tradicional, pelo URL `/wp-login.php?action=register` há alguma forma de se criar uma página personalizada e chamar esse mesmo *form*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ** É melhor passar pelo caminho que mencionei na resposta, pois ao
>   modificar a estrutura do login do painel do Wordpress, colocará em risco seu site e
>   seus usuários em termos de segurança e com updates constantes do
>   Wordpress, você terá problemas futuros oriundos dessa modificação.

Tem com certeza como criar uma página de registro de usuários usando até mesmo outra tabela e sistema de `login` e `session` e listagem de usuários e etc. Se você for programador, acessando com ftp esta pasta do seu site em `wp-content/themes/meu-tema/`, você abrirá o page.php e colocará o seguinte código neste arquivo logo abaixo de `<?php get_header(); ?>`

```
<?php /* Template name: Meu Formulário Personalizado */ ?>
```

Fazendo isso e salvando o arquivo com o nome `page_form_customizado.php` por exemplo (não substitua o seu page.php), ao entrar na área administrativa do Wordpress e clicar em criar nova página, na lista suspensa de modelos de páginas localizado na barra lateral direita, estará escrito `Meu Formulário Personalizado` que ao ser selecionado e uma vez publicado a página e seu conteúdo aparecerá no site.

A partir daí, basta você fazer todas as suas manipulações em qualquer linguagem de programação aceita pelo seu servidor e que não entre em conflito com código existente, por exemplo de javascript, e visualizar a página que o seu formulário e toda a estrutura dele estará sendo executado em front e backend do seu site para fazer aquilo que você determinou.

Também poderá instalar plugins com ou sem shortcodes para fazer o que precisa dentro dessa página personalizada. Mais alguma dúvida?

Resumindo:

1 - Acessa a pasta do seu tema ativo via FTP.

2 - Cria na pasta do tema ativo `page_form_customizado.php` com mesmo conteúdo de page.php

3 - Coloca `<?php /* Template name: Meu Formulário Personalizado */ ?>` e salva.

4 - Vai na área administrativa e ativa a página personalizada.

5 - Insere conteúdo via Wordpress ou programação.

Comment: Você tem razão @Bacco, foi realmente só um acerto do texto. Deixa eu modificar o destaque.

Comment: Seria interessante deixar a palavra Wordpress no título para fins de indexação do Google no sentido em que se a pessoa buscar por `página personalizada no Wordpress` encontrará exatamente a resposta que precisa @Bacco

Comment: pra isso existem as tags, o sistema ja foi feito pensando nisso. a palavra wordpress além da tag, aparece no corpo da pergunta. Daria até pra manter no título, mas não acho que isso vá fazer tanta diferença (mas sinta-se a vontade pra sugerir como edição, clicando no "editar" debaixo da pergunta, se achar realmente necessário).

Comment: Confira o `<title>` desta página para ver como a tag é incorporada automaticamente.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro deste novo template você utiliza a própria API do WP pro CRUD de usuários:

Por exemplo a função wp_create_user, mostrada a seguir:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user

Se a página precisar de autenticação pode chamar outras funções da API como:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_authenticate

Enfim, da feita que criar o template é só trabalhar com a API que da pra fazer o que voce quer tranquilamente.

Answer (score 0):

Para facilitar, acredito que seja melhor utilizar um plugin. Recomendo o [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/)

Dentro da pasta do plugin, há uma pasta chamada templates, que você pode modificar livremente o codigo, sem precisar se preocupar com estar criando alguma falha de segurança em sua plataforma.